# Passing names of functions to another function with parameters as input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, parameter-passing, user-input

**Problem Statement:** I am trying to write MATLAB code for a main caller function (like *run_experiment* below) to specify which computations I want to execute where computations are made sequentially using other MATLAB functions. Those other functions are to be evaluated based on parameters passed with the main caller function. The said functions used in computations are to be specified with name of the scripts they are written in.

**Example Desired Code Behavior:** For example, a command like the following should run the *preprocess_data*, *initialise_model* and *train_model* scripts.

```
>> run_experiment('dataset_1_options', '|preprocess_data|initialise_model|train_model|');
```

And this command should run only the *train_model* script but also evaluates its performance:

```
>> run_experiment('dataset_1_options', '|train_model|evaluate_model|');
```

In the above examples "|" is used as a delimiter to specify separate function names to be evaluated. Those functions use the options specified with *dataset_1_options*. Please do not focus on how to separate that part of the input into meaningful function names; I know how to do it with *strsplit*.

**Constraints and Specifications**: The function names to be passed as input to the main caller function are NOT anonymous functions. **The purpose is to be able to pass such multiple function names as input AND to evaluate them with the options like the above example.** They return output to be evaluated in other parts of the research code (i.e. passing data matrices to other functions within the research code as results of the computations carried out within them.)

**Question:** Given the desired behavior and constraints mentioned above, can anybody help in how to pass the separate function names from another caller function along with options/parameter to those functions? How should the main caller function evaluate the function names passed in as input with the options specified during the call?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass functions to functions in matlab. You just need to use the @ sign when you pass it. In your case it would be run_experiment('dataset_1_options', @train_model) inside a script. You could keep your options in a cell array or something. The run_experiment function would just be a regular function,

```
function [output] = run_experiment(options, train_model, ...);
train_model(options{1}, ...)
.
.
.
end
```

Comment: But I would like to specify multiple function names like in my example desired code behavior to be specified. Those will be the different function names to executed one after another based on my selection of the script names defining those functions.

Comment: So cant you just put in multiple functions using the method I described above? You could have them evaluate with if statements. If the passed parameter is a function you could use the matlab isa function to detect type. I think this may be a case for using varargin. varargin would let you put in a variable amount of arguments as a cell array. Inside your run_experiment code you could have if statements that detect functions.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do this is create a cell array with your function names and another array with the corresponding options as below

```
% Function name array
fn_array = {@fn_1, @fn_2, ...};
% Option array
option_array = {{fn1_opt1, fn2opt2, ...}; {fn2_opt1, fn2_opt2, ...};, ...};
```

These two need to be passed to your run_experiment function which will evaluate them as below

```
function run_experiment(fn_array, option_array)
num_fn = length(fn_array); %Finds number of functions to evaluate
for ii = 1:num_fn %Evaluates each function
    fn_array{ii}(option_array{ii}{:});
end
```